# purge worker, purge coordinator, shutdown handler stuck

Tags: mariadb

I can't make out if the following is a problem or not, and what the solution might be.

```
show processlist;
+--------+------------------+-----------+-------------------+---------+------+--------------------------+------------------+----------+
| Id     | User             | Host      | db                | Command | Time | State                    | Info             | Progress |
+--------+------------------+-----------+-------------------+---------+------+--------------------------+------------------+----------+
|      2 | system user      |           | NULL              | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB purge worker      | NULL             |    0.000 |
|      1 | system user      |           | NULL              | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB purge worker      | NULL             |    0.000 |
|      3 | system user      |           | NULL              | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB purge worker      | NULL             |    0.000 |
|      4 | system user      |           | NULL              | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB purge coordinator | NULL             |    0.000 |
|      5 | system user      |           | NULL              | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB shutdown handler  | NULL             |    0.000 |
| 175658 | jma_staging_user | localhost | autismontario_civ | Query   |    0 | Init                     | show processlist |    0.000 |
+--------+------------------+-----------+-------------------+---------+------+--------------------------+------------------+----------+`
```

The system user processors seem stuck and haven't changed for the last 20 minutes that I've looked.

Server version: 10.3.11-MariaDB MariaDB Server

Comment: Why do you think they are stuck? They are sitting in the background waiting in case they are needed.

Comment: Those are background tasks.  No problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These threads are not a problem as they are normal background tasks with nothing to do at the moment.